# How to keep discord bot online without a server

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have a python script that contains code for the discord bot. When I run it, it activates the discord bot and shows the status for the bot as *online*. But, when I end the python script, it disables the bot. How could I keep the bot active *without* using a server even when I'm offline?

Comment: If the code isn't running, the bot wont run, simple as that. Which means you either need to leave your computer on and connected all the time, or you need to get a dedicated server to run your code for you.

Comment: @squaswin Thanks for the comment, but the only way to run the code all the time is to set up a computer that is powered on forever and run the code on it, but that doesn't make any difference from a server...

Comment: That's the thing though... That's literally what you have to do. If nothing is running your code full time then your code simply doesn't run. If you have a smaller bot though, you might be able to run it on something like a Raspberry Pi. Once it's set up, you should be able to access it via SSH, and it's a lot less power intensive than a dedicated computer is.

Comment: Unless you mean that you just want the status to show as online, in which case you *still* need to run the code full time as Discord sets an account to offline when it can't find a connection to a client with that username.

Comment: @squaswin So, what your'e saying is that there's no other way to keep a bot online except using a server

Comment: Correct. Server, dedicated machine or shared host.

Answer (score 1):

I used a keep_alive script on mine.

Add to start of main.py code:

```
from keep_alive import keep_alive
```

Add to bottom of main.py code:

```
keep_alive()
```

Then create a file called `keep_alive.py`, and add the code:

```
from flask import Flask
from threading import Thread

app = Flask('')

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return "Server Host Connected and Synced to Main Code."

def run():
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=8080)

def keep_alive():  
    t = Thread(target=run)
    t.start()
```

If you make a file called `requirements.txt`, or use it if you already have one.
Add:

```
flask
```

If the bot is Python this should work. It works for me on repl.it

Answer (score -4):

Maybe try using `if/else` statements, so something like:

```
User = (your userID)
Bot = (Bot userID)
If User online keep Bot online
Else keep Bot online
```